# how to Load multiple excel files from sharepoint in Qliksense?

Tags: sql, automation, qliksense

How can i load all the files under a folder in sharepoint  provided: File names are different but Sheet name( from where data will be loaded ) is same as well as the data format.

In Pic If i have to load all 3 files with just one Sharepoint connection  web connector of Parent Folder how do i do that?

Given: Data is in File1,2,3 in Same Sheet ( name: DATA) in the same table format
[image: SharePoint Tree]

Comment: Hi @neelanjoyb, did you found any solution for this?